# How use Topshelf command line to install with service recovery?

Tags: command-line, windows-services, topshelf

Currently, I install my Topshelf Windows Services with the command line

```
my.exe install -instance:1 -username:bob -password:pwd
```

Does anyone know how, if possible, to include Service Recovery Options?
I dont' see anything in the command line reference
http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html

If not supported, what are my options?
Can you use sc.exe (Service Control Manager) on TopShelf Windows Services?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019.aspx

Or should I just suck it up and use the application config file to put these settings in, and read the values to do it programmatically?
http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#id1

```
HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.EnableServiceRecovery(rc =>
    {
        rc.RestartService(1); // restart the service after 1 minute
        rc.RestartSystem(1, "System is restarting!"); // restart the system after 1 minute
        rc.RunProgram(1, "notepad.exe"); // run a program
        rc.SetResetPeriod(1); // set the reset interval to one day
    })
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dotnet Windows service setting up Recovery option using Managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895691/dotnet-windows-service-setting-up-recovery-option-using-managed-code)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not currently possible. But I would encourage you to open a pull request implementing this. I don't recall anyone else asking for this, but it seems like a reasonable request - so at least open an issue in our issue tracker on the [Topshelf GitHub repo](https://GitHub.com/Topshelf/Topshelf).