# Dotnet Windows service setting up Recovery option using Managed code

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, windows-services

I'm having a windows service which is developed using .net framework 4.6.1. While installing the service, I want to Programmatically set the Recovery option of the service. Is there any option using managed code to do this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a tool call Topshelf (http://topshelf-project.com/ )  Which is helping me to set  Recovery option programmatically. Just answering my own question. It will be helpful for others.